# Is there a quicker way of telling if a polynomial of two variables is irreducible?

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

Let's have a more concrete example, suppose we are considering $\mathbb{R}[X,Y]$ and $P(X,Y)=X^3+Y^3.$ Well I can tell that $X+Y$ is a factor straight away and I am left with $X^2-XY+Y^2$ but I cannot tell straightaway wether this is irreducible or not.

What I did was using quadratic formula by holding either $X$ or $Y$ constant to consider further its reducibility. However I am just a bit curious if there is a quicker way of doing this? Because had my polynomial being any higher 'degree' then I will be in a lot of trouble. Is there a trick where we can perhaps convert $\mathbb{R}[X,Y]$ into something we are more familiar about?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Usually degree arguments and consideration of cases are sufficient in the small degree examples.  Here your polynomial is homogeneous of degree two, so you could reduce consideration to the related univariate polynomial in $z=X/Y$.

Comment: Indeed, @hardmath , maybe OP would like an argument based on the clear factorization of $X^2-XY+Y^2$ over $\Bbb C$ and the observation that there’s no way of converting it to a real factorization.

Comment: I’m sorry that you chose the homogeneous polynomial $X^3+Y^3$. In two variables, homogeneous $\Bbb C$-polynomials are always completely reducible, as @hardmath hints. You should expect that a “random” nonhomogeneous polynomial will be irreducible, even over the complex numbers. Take $X^3+Y^3-1$, for instance.

Comment: @Lubin:  JustWandering does ask about $\mathbb R[X,Y]$, so reducing over $\mathbb C$ might not be of interest.

Comment: In two variables the Eisenstein-Dumas criterion applies, see e.g. "Absolute Irreducibility of Polynomials via Newton Polytopes" by Gao.

Comment: Well, @hardmath , you’re not reducing when you’re moving to a larger base. The fact that there *is* a factorization in $\Bbb C[X,Y]$, which is UFD, and the fact that this factorization can not be written over $\Bbb R$, shows that it’s irreducible over the reals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general it's just hard but there are some methods that are easy when they work. Here are some exercises involving checking whether a polynomial in two variables is irreducible in roughly increasing order of difficulty, with spoilered solutions describing the techniques involved.

**Exercise 1:** When is the polynomial $ax^2 + bxy + cy^2$ irreducible?

> This polynomial is homogeneous (every term has degree $2$), so if it factors it must factor into homogeneous polynomials (exercise). Hence any factorization must have the form $(px + qy)(rx + sy)$, and we see that as long as $a \neq 0$ the problem is the same as factoring the dehomogenized polynomial $at^2 + bt + c$ where $t = \frac{x}{y}$, and similarly as long as $c \neq 0$ the problem is the same as factoring the dehomogenized polynomial $a + bt + ct^2$ where now $t = \frac{y}{x}$. Either way the answer, over $\mathbb{R}$, is: if and only if the discriminant $\Delta = b^2 - 4ac$ is negative.

**Exercise 2:** When is the polynomial $y^2 - (x^3 + ax + b)$ irreducible?

(This is the (affine) equation of an [elliptic curve in Weierstrass form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve).)

> This polynomial is neither homogeneous nor quadratic. However, it is quadratic considered as a polynomial in $y$ only (with coefficients in $\mathbb{R}[x]$ or, if you prefer, the fraction field $\mathbb{R}(x)$), and considering it as a polynomial in $y$ only, if it has a nontrivial factorization it must have the form $(y - f(x))(y - g(x))$ where $f, g$ are polynomials in $x$. Expanding this out we get that $f(x) = - g(x)$ so in fact the factorization must have the form $(y - f(x))(y + f(x)) = y^2 - f(x)^2$; in other words, this polynomial factors iff $x^3 + ax + b$ is a square. But a square polynomial must have even degree! The conclusion is that this polynomial is always irreducible.

**Exercise 3:** Is the polynomial $(y^3 - y) - (x^6 - 1)$ irreducible?

(There's nothing special about this polynomial.)

> This example is neither homogeneous nor quadratic in either variable so we'll need a new idea. We can do the following: it is cubic in $y$, so it factors as a polynomial in $y$ iff it has a linear factor as a polynomial in $y$, and we can test possible linear factors using a generalization of the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem), which here tells us that if $y - f(x)$ is a linear factor then $f(x)$ must divide $x^6 - 1$, whose irreducible factorization over $\mathbb{R}$ is $(x - 1)(x + 1)(x^2 - x + 1)(x^2 + x + 1)$. In order for $y - f(x)$ to be a linear factor, or equivalently for $f(x)$ to be a root of the above polynomial (as a polynomial in $y$), degree considerations show that $f$ must be quadratic, and now you can just check that none of the possible quadratics $f(x) = x^2 - 1, x^2 - x + 1, x^2 + x + 1$ work. So the polynomial is irreducible.

Answer (score 2):

In two variables there is an irreducibility criterion called the Eisenstein-Dumas criterion, which generalises the Eisenstein criterion over $\mathbb Q$ and in which the role of the prime $p$ is played by the indeterminate $Y$ (which generates a prime ideal in $k[X,Y]$).

> Let $F$ be any field and $f=f_0(Y)+f_1(Y)X+\cdots+f_n(Y)X^n$ such that $f_0(Y)\neq 0$ and such that $f_n(Y)$ is a nonzero constant in $F$. If the Newton polygon of $f$ has only one line segment from $(0,m)$ to $(n,0)$ and $\gcd(n,m)=1$, then $f$ is irreducible over $F$, as well as any algebraic extension of $F$.

The Newton polygon in question is the lower convex hull of the points $(0,d_0)$, $(1,d_1)$, $\dots$, $(n-1,d_{n-1})$ and $(n,0)$ where $d_i$ is the degree of $f_i(Y)$ with $d_0=m$ and $d_n=0$.

For example, if $f=aY^m+bX^vY^w+cX^n\in F[x,y]$ with $a,b,c,m,n,v,w\neq 0$ and $(v,w)$ is not on the line $y=-\frac mnx+m$, then the corresponding Newton polygon is the triangle with vertices $(0,m)$, $(v,w)$ and $(n,0)$. Since there is only one line segment from $(0,m)$ to $(n,0)$, the polynomial $f$ will be irreducible over $F$ if $\gcd (m,n)=1$.

The paper [Absolute Irreducibility of Polynomials via Newton Polytopes](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869300985867) by S. Gao gives more criteria and examples for absolute irreducibility (irreducibility over $\mathbb C$) for multivariate polynomials.